# use kivy.graphics whit scrollview

Tags: python, kivy

I use kivy.graphics.line to draw a diagram
i want to use scrollview when the width of my diagram is too large

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import  Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line

   
class Graph(Screen, MDApp):
    def drawLine(self):
        z = 18
        Xs = 50
        Ys = 150
        Step = 50
        h0=3
        h1 = 40
        h2 = 80
        h3 = 90
        s = 1.5
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1)
            for i in range(1,z+2):
                Line(points=[Xs+(i*Step), Ys, Xs+(i*Step), Ys+h1],width=1.4)
            Line(points=[Xs+Step, Ys, Xs+((z+1)*Step), Ys],width=1.4)
            Line(points=[Xs+Step, Ys+h1, Xs+((z+1)*Step), Ys+h1],width=1.4)

            Color(1, 0.2, 0.2, 1)
            for i in [1,7,13]:
                Line(points=[Xs+Step//2+(i*Step), Ys+h1+h2, Xs+Step//2+((i+s)*Step), Ys+h1+h2+h3],width=2)
                Line(points=[Xs+Step//2+(i*Step), Ys+h0+h1, Xs+Step//2+(i*Step), Ys+h1+h2],width=2)
            for i in [4,10,16]:
                Line(points=[Xs+Step//2+(i*Step), Ys+h1+h2, Xs+Step//2+((i-s)*Step), Ys+h1+h2+h3],width=2)
                Line(points=[Xs+Step//2+(i*Step), Ys+h0+h1, Xs+Step//2+(i*Step), Ys+h1+h2],width=2)

            Color(0.2, 1, 0.2, 1)
            for i in [3,9,15]:
                Line(points=[Xs+Step//2+(i*Step), Ys+h1+h2, Xs+Step//2+((i+s)*Step), Ys+h1+h2+h3],width=2)
                Line(points=[Xs+Step//2+(i*Step), Ys+h0+h1, Xs+Step//2+(i*Step), Ys+h1+h2],width=2)
            for i in [6,12,18]:
                Line(points=[Xs+Step//2+(i*Step), Ys+h1+h2, Xs+Step//2+((i-s)*Step), Ys+h1+h2+h3],width=2)
                Line(points=[Xs+Step//2+(i*Step), Ys+h0+h1, Xs+Step//2+(i*Step), Ys+h1+h2],width=2)
            
            Color(0.2, 0.2, 1, 1)
            for i in [17,5,11]:
                Line(points=[Xs+Step//2+(i*Step), Ys+h1+h2, Xs+Step//2+((i+s)*Step), Ys+h1+h2+h3],width=2)
                Line(points=[Xs+Step//2+(i*Step), Ys+h0+h1, Xs+Step//2+(i*Step), Ys+h1+h2],width=2)
            for i in [2,8,14]:
                Line(points=[Xs+Step//2+(i*Step), Ys+h1+h2, Xs+Step//2+((i-s)*Step), Ys+h1+h2+h3],width=2)
                Line(points=[Xs+Step//2+(i*Step), Ys+h0+h1, Xs+Step//2+(i*Step), Ys+h1+h2],width=2)
    pass

Builder.load_file("Graph.kv")
class myapp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Graph()

myapp().run()
```

Graph.kv

```
<Graph>:
    MDGridLayout:
        cols:1
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text:"Gragh"
            on_release: root.drawLine()
```

[Before drawing the diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQVas.png)

[After drawing the diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg3Gf.png)

[To see the diagram in full, the width of the window should be increased](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k13g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do that is to always include a `ScrollView`. Try modifying your `Graph.kv` to:

```
#:import ScrollEffect kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect
ScrollView:
    do_scroll_y: False
    effect_x: ScrollEffect()
    Graph:
        size_hint_x: None
    
<Graph>:
    MDGridLayout:
        cols:1
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text:"Gragh"
            on_release: root.drawLine()
```

Then move the `Builder.load_file()` call into the `build()` method, like this:

```
class myapp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("Graph.kv")
```

You will also need a statement in your `drawLine()` method that sets the width of the `Graph` large enough to contain the drawing. Something like:

```
self.width = 1000
```

This should result in a `ScrollView` that will not scroll unless the `Graph` width is larger than the App window.

Comment: thank you I made a few changes like you said and it worked perfectly.

Comment: But it does not work in a multi-screen program
The screens are in separate files